# labeling leaf nodes in tree (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got an xml, that I want to process, and simply label in turn each leaf node, flip or flip in turn, unless some condition is met.

take for example this xml

```
<root>
   <tx>
      <alloc>
         <event>a</event>
         <event>b</event>
      </alloc>
      <alloc>
         <event>c</event>
         <event>d</event>
         <event>d1</event>
      </alloc>
   </tx>
   <tx>
      <alloc>
         <event>e</event>
         <event>f</event>
         <event>g</event>
      </alloc>
   </tx>
</root>
```

and lets say we want to label each event node, flip then flip then flip, etc UNLESS the event is "e"

note the labelling of the events is independent of the hierachy.

so...

```
<root>
   <tx>
      <alloc>
         <event flip="true">a</event>
         <event flip="false">b</event>
      </alloc>
      <alloc>
         <event flip="true">c</event>
         <event flip="false">d</event>
         <event flip="true">d1</event>
      </alloc>
   </tx>
   <tx>
      <alloc>
         <event flip="true">e</event>
         <event flip="false">f</event>
         <event flip="true">g</event>
      </alloc>
   </tx>
</root>
```

so node "d1" is "true" AND "e" stays "true" before carrying on, because of our rule.

now...I CAN see a way to do it, but it doesnt feel as if it fits XSLT very nicely.

If I were to do this in some functional language I would recursive process the tree, basically cloning it, passing the value of flip/flop through each recursive function so something like...

so for example the tx processing template would look something like this (this is made up)

```
   <xsl:template match="tx" mode="label">
      <xsl:param name="flip_flip"/>
      <xsl:variable name="allocations">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="alloc" mode="label">
            <xsl:with-param name="flip_flip" select="$flip_flop"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$allocations"/>
      <xsl:variable name="new_flip_flip" select="alloc/event/@flip[last()]"
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::tx[1]" mode="label">
         <xsl:with-param name="flip_flip" select="$new_flip_flip + 1"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>
```

i.e. process each element in turn, pull out the last calculated flip flop value, and then process the next one.

feels ugly in xslt.

another option would be to count the number of preceding events, take off the number of exceptions and then work out mod 2 if flip is true or false.
again, feels clunky, and computationally expensive.

Comment: achch sorry...you, of course have to have 1 hand tied behdin your back...i.e. XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="event">
    <xsl:variable name="i">
        <xsl:number count="event[not(.='e')]" level="any" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <event flip="{boolean($i mod 2)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </event>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've not used number/count/any...let me look that up

Comment: ok, this works for my example, but it would have to count preceding event nodes, not all.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "preceding".

Comment: we label in turn, in document order, in your example if there are two <event>e<event> then wouldnt it simply go false/true/false/true?

Comment: ah...I think your solution does work...I just don't understand it!...let me look closer

Comment: ah no this isnt right...let me try to explain

Comment: this is "counting" in the context of a parent node....it needs to count in the context of the document.

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. Please provide an example of input where this fails. (Not in a comment, of course.)

Comment: P.S. You can use `<event i="{$i}">` to see the actual count.

Comment: yeah I've done the $i thing...let me just check the updated example fails

Comment: I've updated the exampe..."d1" is true....the subsequent "e" is false...it should be true too

Comment: and the {$i} shows a count in the context of its parent element

Comment: I am getting a different result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1a5

Comment: its because I'm an idiot!!!!...did you just add an "any"?

Comment: I had it in my original answer. I have mistakenly removed it in an edit and restored it 5 minutes later. You must have fallen in the crack.

Comment: how would i do it if the rule was, if the NEXT event was an "e"?

Comment: I guess (!) you could count `event[not(following::event[1]='e')]`? If not, post a new question with a proper example.

Comment: actually ignore me...the original answer works for me, thanks v much